# How to add zero decimal points to all elements of a matrix in shell

Tags: awk, integer, decimal, floating

I have a file containing integer and floating numbers which has 3 columns and many lines. I want to have all the numbers in floating format which 6 significant figures, i.e. the number `2` becomes `2.000000`. I already tried this script but it only works for one column. I appreciate if you help me how to due it for the next two columns to or any other one line script which can do the job. Thanks in advance

```
awk '{printf "%.6f\n",$1}' file
```

Comment: If you are only printing `$1` (the first field), why would you expect the other fields would change. `for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) printf "  %.6f", i; print ""`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Should not that be `$i`, since `i` will just print field number, not the field.

Comment: Doah.... you are correct @Jotne, it should be `$i` (I must have been thinking `for (i in ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you provided works for only one column because you are only printing the first column in the script. If you have only 3 columns and if the number of columns is fixed you just need to add the other two columns to your print statement to make it work.

For example:

```
awk '{printf "%.6f %.6f %.6f \n",$1,$2,$3}'
```

If the number of columns is unknown you can use a loop inside awk to print all the columns. `NF` will give the total number of records. You can iterate through it and print the results.

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<= NF; i++) printf "%.6f ",$i; print "" }' input
```

You also can use this script to print the three columns as required, if your file only contains three columns (`NF` is 3 in that case).

As pointed out by **@kvantour** in comments, an elegant way to write the above one liner is:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%.6f" (i==NF?ORS:OFS), $i}
```

Essentially, both one-liners do the same thing but the `ORS` (Output Record Separator) and `OFS` (Output Field Separator) variables give the flexibility to change the output easily and quickly.

So, `(i==NF?ORS:OFS)` what it does is, if the field is not the last column then `OFS` is printed (`OFS` is a space by default) and if it is the last column then `ORS` is printed (default value of `ORS` is newline ). Advantage of using these separator variables are, for example, if you want to have two new lines instead of a single newline between rows in the results it can be easily set using `ORS="\n\n"`

Comment: @kvantour Thank you for pointing it out. Edited and corrected the answer.

Comment: While this answer is good, it is always better to make use of variables like `OFS` and `ORS` for output. This way, people can quickly redefine the output separators and achieve the same, or incorporate it in other scripts. This said, the above could be written as: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%.6f" (i==NF?ORS:OFS), $i}'`

Comment: @kvantour Thanks again. I have updated the answer with the comments you have provided.

Comment: Thank you all. That worked perfect and solved my problem :)

Comment: @AminAlibakhshi Glad it helped :) . You can accept the answer if it solved the problem as expected.

Comment: thanks @j23. How can I accept the answer? sorry I am very new in this website.

Comment: @AminAlibakhshi [Please see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)